# remove system menu tab from magento

Tags: magento

I am currently using the adminhtml.xml file of my module to remove some elements from the top admin menu like this:

```
<config>
<menu>
    <system>
        <children>
            <tools>
                <disabled>1</disabled>
            </tools>
```

And works fine. I want to do the same for system_config items, like Advanced > Developer for example but I can't figure out the correct syntax to use. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to say that if you want to remove some menu item then please create new admin user at admin side and select the menu item that you want to appear on top menu.and just logged in with that user/pass.

Comment: Freedom is right. create a role and remove permissions of the menu item and assign that role to a user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For config tabs it doesn't work like that.
But you can observe the event `adminhtml_init_system_config`. There you should receive as a parameter all the `system.xml` files merged into one by xml.
You can remove certain sections and tabs in your observer.